# PHP download image from url without direct image name

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, php-5.6

```
{{my_salesforce_url}}/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0694U000007w5QyQAI?operationContext=S1
```

this url content a file with name ine_file.jpg, when run in browser work and download the file direct, but when i try download with php and save the file in local no work

i try with:

```
file_put_contents(public_path() . "/" . $fileName, fopen($file["url"], 'r'));
```

and

```
    file_put_contents(public_path() . "/" . $fileName, file_get_contents($url));
```

any idea ?
How to get a file from url and save the file using php o curl?

Comment: are you getting an error message? What does file_put_contents and file_get_contents return?

Comment: Do you need a login to view that image? Perhaps your PHP need to be authorized to access your sales force content? Maybe you should be looking into the sales force Rest API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you are downloading from a secured server

```
$options = array(
"ssl" => array(
    "verify_peer" => false,
    "verify_peer_name" => false,
),
);
$image = file_get_contents('www.example.com/image.jpg', false, stream_context_create($options));
$filename = 'filename.jpg';     
$filedir = 'public/uploads/' . $filename;
file_put_contents($filedir, $image);
```